# IOS ItunesU search api?

Tags: ios7, itunesu

I am trying to embed an ItuensU search feature inside my app. My question is what api I can use get the result which can be exactly same to the result user gets from Itunes search? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried looking here? https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have tried the search api although I am not sure how it'd work with iTunes U. Can you make me an example(i.e. url)?